# Cannot find control with path 'myFormArray -> [index] -> myProperty

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I'm trying to generate a dynamic form using Angular ReactiveForms.
Currently I'm getting the error `Cannot find control with path 'myFormArray -> [index] -> myProperty`. I've already checked some answer found in internet but without success. Here my code:

**HTML:**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <div formArrayName="myFormArray" *ngFor="let ctrl of foo.controls; let i=index">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
            <input matInput type="text" formControlName="myProperty">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**TS:**

```
export class MyClass implements OnChanges {

  @Input() myData: any;

  myForm: FormGroup;

  get foo(): FormArray{
    return <FormArray>this.myForm.get('myFormArray');
  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (!this.myForm) {
      this.myForm = this.fb.group({
        myFormArray: this.fb.array([this.buildMyFormArray()])
      });
    }

    this.myForm.setControl('myFormArray', this.fb.array(myData || []));
  }

  buildMyFormArray(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      myProperty: ''
    });
  }
}
```

`myData` comes from parent as input in the component and it looks like

```
myData: [
    { myProperty: 'John Doe' },
    { myProperty: 'Jane Doe' },
    { myProperty: 'Jack Doe' }
]
```

The error occurs for each item in the data array changing the index in the middle.

Can you help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `myFormArray` control is supposed to be a `FormArray` of `FormGroup`s but you're creating `FormArray` of `FormControl`s.

So let's try the following:

```
this.myForm.setControl('myFormArray', 
   this.fb.array((this.myData || []).map((x) => this.fb.group(x))));
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/nCHlyurV32GBJXm7vV1h?layout=1)**

Comment: @yurzui Great !!